Google OAuth2 Refresh Access Token, Bad Request Invalid Grant (for some users not all)
My business has been dealing with refresh token's becoming invalid to some of our clients, the user needs to sign back in because the refresh token no longer works.  We have a handful of long standing connected clients that do not need to be reauthenticated.  Although some clients are connected for a couple days at a time then the refresh token dies and no longer works, we are trying to get to the bottom of this but have come up short.  We even contacted the clients and they have not changed their password or revoked the app.
What I can say is:

We request refresh token calls that happen about 2hrs throughout the day everyday, which is outside of the normal 1 hour access token range
We do not change scopes, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
We are using offline
Our app is in production
Our app has been submitted successfully, verified and approved. Although the oauth consent form had a minor update some years ago replacing the logo with a more updated version and currently the app sits to be verified but still functions the same.

Has anyone else experienced this, is there anything else I should look at?
